# How to select the Shape to use as Mask in XD?

Tags: mask, adobe-xd

I have 2 rectangles, a big one and a small one. The big one has round edges.

If I select both of them and click to "Mask with Shape", Adobe XD will always use the small rectangle as the mask, but I want to use the big rectangle as the mask, so the round edges of it will mask the small rectangle edges.

Is it possible to choose who's gonna mask who?

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the layer stacking order most of the time: the topmost object you have selected becomes the mask shape, and any other selected object(s) are the content that gets masked.

I believe there's an exception to this if the topmost object has an image fill. Then XD assumes you meant that to be the content and uses the *other* shape in the selection as the mask instead.